# How to set up slide duration at bxslider

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I know I can set the speed of the transition (with `speed`). But is there any option to set the duration a slide is shown until the transition to the next slide begins?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Using the `pause` option:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    pause: 3000
});
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Yq3RM/202/

**Update**

Another example that modifies the pause for each image. bxSlider doesn't have a nice built in way to do this that I am aware of, however I was able to pull it off in the following way:

```
var ImagePauses = [1000,3000,6000,9000,12000,15000];

var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
modifyDelay(0);

function modifyDelay(startSlide){
    slider.reloadSlider({
        mode: 'horizontal',
        infiniteLoop: true,
        auto: true,
        autoStart: true,
        autoDirection: 'next',
        autoHover: true,
        pause: ImagePauses[startSlide],
        autoControls: false,
        pager: true,
        pagerType: 'full',
        controls: true,
        captions: true,
        speed: 500,
        startSlide: startSlide,
        onSlideAfter: function($el,oldIndex, newIndex){
            modifyDelay(newIndex);  
        } 
    });
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yq3RM/904/)

Comment: Is it possible to set duration for individual slides?

Comment: @GDmac it is possible, however I have to essentially reinitialize the slider everytime, I'm not sure what impact this might have on performance but the example code ran smoothly for me.  See the update in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for a solution, bxslider uses an interval instead of a timeOut. I'm considering to set autoplay to off and hook into the various callbacks myself to set timeout (i also want to autoplay video in any slides and after playback advance to the next slide)