# Bxslider set different side pause length hangs on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I am looking to solve a problem with bxslider regarding setting a different pause length for each slide. I initially followed the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21683080/how-to-set-up-slide-duration-at-bxslider) and it worked great for 5 or 6 slides but after the sideshow grew past 10-15, the spinner just hangs now:

[Screenshot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tYoZ.png)

Here's the slider code I'm using based on the above example:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var ImagePauses = [15000,15000,15000,15000,15000,15000,15000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,5000,5000,5000,5000,5000,5000,5000];

    var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
    modifyDelay(0);

    function modifyDelay(startSlide){
        slider.reloadSlider({
            mode: 'horizontal',
            //infiniteLoop: true,
            auto: true,
            autoStart: true,
            autoDirection: 'next',
            autoHover: true,
            pause: ImagePauses[startSlide],
            autoControls: false,
            pager: true,
            pagerType: 'full',
            controls: true,
            //captions: true,
            //speed: 500,
            startSlide: startSlide,
            onSlideAfter: function($el,oldIndex, newIndex){
                modifyDelay(newIndex);  
            } 
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Is there anything glaring that I'm missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### UPDATE

It seems there's more involved in making bxSlider custom auto features. I realized that `setTimeout()`, `goToNextSlide()`, and `goToSlide()` methods are not needed if the `auto` option is used.

I made 3 object literals, each representing a bxSlider options. When the next set of intervals up, a `switch()` will call `reloadSlider()` method with the next set of bxSlider options.

---

#### OLD

We can control the delay of the slide intervals by using the callback `onSlideAfter` and the callback function called `bxDelay()` uses `setTimeout` and the method `goToNextSlide()`. Details are commented in the source.

#### SNIPPET

```css
.as-console.as-console * {
  background: orange;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>bxArraySourcePauseInterval</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.css">
  <style>
    img {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <ul class="bx">
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/000/fff?text=1">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/00f/fc0?text=2">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/0e0/000?text=3">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/f00/fff?text=4">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/fff/000?text=5">
    </li>
  </ul>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var count = 0;
      var cfg0 = {
        auto: true,
        pause: 3000,
        autoStart: true,
        autoHover: true,
        onSlideAfter: bxDelay
      }
      var cfg1 = {
        auto: true,
        pause: 2000,
        autoStart: true,
        autoHover: true,
        onSlideAfter: bxDelay
      }
      var cfg2 = {
        auto: true,
        pause: 1000,
        autoStart: true,
        autoHover: true,
        onSlideAfter: bxDelay
      }
      var bx = $('.bx').bxSlider(cfg0);

      function bxDelay($obj, from, to) {
        count++;
        switch (count) {
          case 8:
            bx.reloadSlider(cfg1);
            break;
          case 15:
            bx.reloadSlider(cfg2);
            break;
          case 22:
            bx.reloadSlider(cfg0);
            count = 0;
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
        console.log('Count: ' + count);
      }

    });
  </script>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This has solved the loading problem and the explanation and comments have helped me to understand this solution better!

Comment: Glad to help, happy coding.:)

Comment: Just one more question. My delays don't seem to be working properly. All the slides seem to be delayed the same amount and they are way shorter than the times that are set. I can't seem to figure out why. Any thoughts?

Comment: @NPI My bad, see update, it's set at 3, 2, 1 sec because I'm impatient, but it's easily adjusted.